# Where do I get linux-headers-3.0.0 for 12.04

Tags: kernel, dkms, tp-smapi

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so question may seem stupid.

I have a module which used to work on my parents laptop. After several updates module no longer works, and I'm pretty sure, old kernel would solve the issue.

However, I can't rebuild module with dkms for an old 3.0.0-16 kernel, because there are no kernel sources. linux-headers-3.0.0 is NOT in the repository. However linux-image-3.0.0-generic still exists in the repo.

So where do I get headers for an old kernel?

Thanks

Comment: *"`linux-image-3.0.0-generic` still exists in the repo"* [No it doesn't](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-3&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all). Did you upgrade from 11.10? Then it might be still on your system, but it's not supported for 12.04.

Comment: apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: I have linux-image-3.0.0-generic on my system and cat boot it via grub. However, as I said, dkms fails to recompile module for that kernel. And the only package for linux-3.0.0 is linux-image, which is not enough for dkms to work.